# MySQL Still purging binary logs and ignoring expire_logs_days

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, logs, gtid

We are running mysql v5.6.17 and I cannot find if there is something else that is causing the binary logs to be purged other than the following:

- Adding `expire_logs_days` to the my.ini (and confirming it is set on the server via `show global variables like 'expire%';`)
- Manually running [PURGE BINARY LOGS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/purge-binary-logs.html)

There is a nightly backup that backs up the main database, compresses it using 7zip and then FTPs it to another server. I found that the binary logs are purged every night to the binary log which was always created at 00:00 midnight. This is an issue as there is a replication machine running which uses GTIDs and it cannot find the binary logs on the master which are specified by the gtid_purged.

I created 2 events to troubleshoot this. The first event to turn on general logging into a table during this period where it was being purged, and a second to turn general logging off a few hours later. The backup starts at 00:05 and the purge is issued at around 00:07

It seems the `PURGE MASTER LOGS TO` command was being run by root[root] @ localhost [::1].

There is no one connecting to the server that would run this.
As far as I understand the `--delete-master-logs` in mysqldump command is similar to `RESET MASTER`, but is not the same as `PURGE BINARY LOGS`. We do not use `--delete-master-logs` however.

What could be causing the purge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you problem is the version of MySQL you are using.

You have MySQL 5.6.17 but the [Change Log for MySQL 5.6.19](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-19.html) has this:

> Replication: When the binary log was rotated due to receipt of a SIGHUP signal, the new binary log did not contain the Previous_gtid_event required for subsequent processing of that binary log's GTID events. Now when SIGHUP is received, steps are taken to insure that the server writes the necessary Previous_gtid_event to the new log before writing any GTID events to the new log. (Bug #17026898)

This could just be speculation, but I suspect that if the I/O thread disconnects when it smells a binary log rotation in its master and [expire_logs_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days) = 1, this bug might be happening because the oldest binary log disappears and a slave's I/O thread get thrown under the bus looking for a GTID value it can no longer see.

You may need to do one of following:

- Upgrade to the latest MySQL 5.6 (5.6.38) or at least 5.6.23
- Change some options

  - Stop using [--flush-logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_flush-logs) with the mysqldump
  - Make your [expire_logs_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days) > 1

As for the disappearing of logs, any time FLUSH LOGS is manually or internally executed, it will delete binary logs older than [expire_logs_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days)*86400 seconds.

I remember years ago that [expire_logs_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days) used to trigger every midnight (I am going way back to 5.0.x). Now, [expire_logs_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days) has seconds granularity.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have tried everything you have mentioned and it still seems to be purging the logs at midnight. The last thing to try is the upgrade. I will get back to you on this.

Comment: it seems by changing the backup time to 1AM instead of 12AM has stopped the server from internally purging the bin logs. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, but too big for a comment.)

Flipping over to a new binlog happens two ways:

- passing `max_binlog_size`, or
- `FLUSH LOGS`

But neither should cause the deletion of the previous binlog without `PURGE` or `expires`.

Sounds like `FLUSH` is happening, probably from the 'nightly backup'.

Please provide the details of your "nightly backup"; the answer is likely to be buried in there somewhere.

Comment: Yes `FLUSH LOGS` is not a problem, but more the purging of the logs. Currently we use this dump - `mysqldump --user=user --password=password --flush-logs --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --databases db1 --triggers --routines | 7z a -aoa -si c:\mysqlbackups\dump.sql.7z `. I intentionally want it to flush, but this should not purge the bin logs. We also have `max_binlog_size` set in the my.ini. Is there anything that would cause the MySQL server to purge the bin logs internally daily, even when there is a expire_logs_days set?